# Multiple OR Statements on Right Side

Tags: elm

I'm baffled as to what I'm missing here.  I am new to Elm but I don't see how this could be wrong:

```
move : List Char -> Char -> Int
move board symbol =
    let
        grid =
            fromList board

         found =
         ((get 0 grid == symbol) && (get 1 grid == symbol) && (get 2 grid == symbol))
           || ((get 4 grid == symbol) && (get 4 grid == symbol) && (get 5 grid == symbol))
    in
    if found then
        1
    else
        0
```

Error:

```
The = operator is reserved for defining variables. Maybe you want == instead? Or
maybe you are defining a variable, but there is whitespace before it?

14|          found =
                         ^
Maybe <http://elm-lang.org/docs/syntax> can help you figure it out.

Detected errors in 1 module.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Elm is sensitive to indentation.

The declarations of `grid` and `found` within your `let` clause must have the same indentation, but `found` is indented by one more space than `grid`.

Try deleting a space so that these two declarations line up.